# How to convert .wav response in to blob url so that I can play as audio in client side using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, blob

I'm doing a rest call which would give me as `wav` response of `audio/mpeg` content type, Something like

```
ID3.O��^H��B��F�����^H��B��F���
```

I want to play this audio on my client side. So I want to create a blob URL for this.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'texttospeechnew2?text='+text+'&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&download=true&accept=audio%2Fmp3',
        type: 'GET',
        //data: params,
        success: function(data) {

            responsefile = data;
             var byteArray = new Uint8Array(responsefile);
            var blob = new Blob(byteArray, { type: "audio/mpeg3" });
            const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);

            console.log(url);


        },
        error: function(data, err) {
            console.log("err");
        }

    });
```

It is giving me blob url but not proper format unable to play that.can someone help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `XMLHttpRequest`

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'texttospeechnew2?text='+text+'&voice=en-US_AllisonVoice&download=true&accept=audio%2Fmp3', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response);
    console.log(url);
  }
};

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Hi...Ive tried It gave me blob url but cant play the audio...Giving following error in console.When I open that bloburl

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)

Comment: Hello.It worked now,actually we mentioned response type as blob so again creating byte array and converting that to blob is not required

Comment: Even this is not required

var blob = new Blob(this.response, { type: "audio/mpeg3" });

Comment: Is it okay, now?